# In a sentence where I define something, am I the arbiter of the word being defined as being singular or plural?

Tags: meaning

...starting the sentence with "X is" or "X are".

"Treasure is minerals and coins amassed together" doesn't sound right, even if I, since I am making the definition, decide to make treasure a singular noun like "people" sometimes is. (Not that I am going to do something like this in practice.)

Comment: "Treasure" is always singular. It can be used as a mass noun, but mass nouns are still grammatically singular in English and take singular verb agreement. I can't think of any grammatical sentence that starts with "Treasure are..."

Answer (score 1):

*Treasure* and *people* are not the same in their plurality. *Treasure* is a mass noun, similar to *furniture* or *water* and therefore is syntactically singular and should always be referred to as such. *Treasure are...* is ungrammatical. You can, however, have *a treasure*, and then use the plural form *treasures*, e.g. a person who refers to his children as his treasures.

*People* is the plural form of the noun *person*, and therefore is syntactically plural and should always be referred to as such, unless you are referring to the word itself (so, you can say "people is the plural form of person").